# Why does this onClickListener give a NullPointerException?

Tags: android, android-studio

In activity

```
borderFav = (Button) findViewById(R.id.borderFav);
fav = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fav);

borderFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                borderFav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                borderFav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

In XML of a RecyclerView item

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/borderFav"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/favorite_border_24"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fav"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/favorite_24"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
```

Logic is simple, empty heart gets clicked, turns into full heart, full heart clicked turns into empty heart, but Logcat gives a NullPointer in the activity.

If I remove the onClickListeners for those two, there is no error.

RecyclerView Adapter code

```
public class AllAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Food> data;
    private OnItemListener onItemListener;

    public ArrayList<Food> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public AllAdapter(ArrayList<Food> data, OnItemListener onItemListener) {
        this.data = data;
        this.onItemListener = onItemListener;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AllAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v, onItemListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AllAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(this.data.get(position).getName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }



    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        private TextView textView;
        private OnItemListener onItemListener;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemListener onItemListener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            this.onItemListener = onItemListener;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemListener.onClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }


    }

    public void filterList(ArrayList<Food> filteredList){
        data = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public interface OnItemListener{
        void onClick(int position);
    }

}
```

I did not touch the Adapter to implement the favourite button.

Comment: Can you paste recyclerview adapter code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your adapter to this and see if it works,

```
public class AllAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Food> data;
    private OnItemListener onItemListener;

    public ArrayList<Food> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public AllAdapter(ArrayList<Food> data, OnItemListener onItemListener) {
        this.data = data;
        this.onItemListener = onItemListener;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AllAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v, onItemListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AllAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(this.data.get(position).getName());

        holder.borderFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.borderFav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.fav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        holder.fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.fav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.borderFav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView textView;
        private Button borderFav, fav;
        private OnItemListener onItemListener;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemListener onItemListener) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            borderFav = itemView.findViewById(R.id.borderFav);
            fav = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fav);
            this.onItemListener = onItemListener;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemListener.onClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public void filterList(ArrayList<Food> filteredList) {
        data = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public interface OnItemListener {
        void onClick(int position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have pasted it seems, you are doing it wrong, the xml items of recyclerview belongs to the recyclerview adapter so you should place those click listeners in your **onBindViewHolder**() rather than inside activity.